# React.js Wierd behaviour

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Consider this simple react component to display a list.

```js
class List extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
      super(props)
      this.data = ["abvjx", "sda", "fdsaf"]
  }   
  getRows(){      
      return this.data.map((el, index)=>{
          return (
            <li>
              {el}
              <button onClick={()=>{alert(index)}}>Click
              </button>
            </li>
          );
      })
  }
  getRows2(){
      let ret = []
      let i = 0
      for (const row of this.data){
          ret.push(
          <li>{row, i}
            <button onClick={()=>{alert(i)}}>Click</button>
          </li>);
          i++;
      }
      return ret
  }
  render(){
      return (
          this.getRows2()
      )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<List />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

`getRows()` returns an array of jsx elements, showing elements from the data array along with it's indexes, every row also has a button which when clicked will show a popup, this popup shows the index of that row.

`getRows2()` does the same except this time im using the `for` of loop instead of `Array.map`.

[Both show the same result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTH0w.png)

But when i click on **any** button when using `getRows2()` the popup always shows 3, whereas `getRows()` shows the correct index in the popup

Comment: It's not React.js, but JavaScript. Read about [closures in JavaScript](https://medium.com/@prashantramnyc/javascript-closures-simplified-d0d23fa06ba4). To explain briefly, All buttons have access to `i`, but the value of `i` is the last index.

Comment: Thanks @AdamAzad, I think i got it, for the function ()=>{alert(i)} i must be otained from the closure. When using map 3 different closures are created while when using for the same closure which has i=3 is used everytime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens the value of `i` is updated before calling the `alert` function.

This is concept called **closure**.

In MDN words:

> A closure is the combination of a function bundled together (enclosed) with references to its surrounding state (the lexical environment). In other words, a closure gives you access to an outer function’s scope from an inner function. In JavaScript, closures are created every time a function is created, at function creation time.

**MDN**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

**Eric Elliot** gives an nice explanation: https://medium.com/javascript-scene/master-the-javascript-interview-what-is-a-closure-b2f0d2152b36

Answer (score 1):

It's simple, you basically are using `i` on its last index.

Here:

```
let i = 0
for (let row of this.data){
    ret.push(
    <li>{row, i}
      <button onClick={()=>{alert(i)}}>Click</button>
    </li>);
    i++;
}
// Since you've been incrementing i within the loop.. any call after the loop to use i is when i=3
```

What happens here is that you register an `onClick` event to `alert(i)`. But that i is independent of each item on loop. `i` is defined outside the loop. So by the time you perform the click event, it's after the buttons are rendered and at that point `i` is already at `i = 3` ... Remember you incremented it on every item of the loop. Hence it keeps showing 3.

---

One of the approaches you could use is try and use `data-*` attribute to store `i`. This is how you may go about it:

```js
class List extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
      super(props)
      this.data = ["abvjx", "sda", "fdsaf"]
  }   
  getRows(){      
      return this.data.map((el, index)=>{
          return (
            <li>
              {el}
              <button onClick={()=>{alert(index)}}>Click
              </button>
            </li>
          );
      })
  }
  getRows2(){
      let ret = []
      let i = 0
      for (const row of this.data){
          ret.push(
          <li>{row, i}
              <button data-i={i} onClick={
                (e) => alert(e.target.getAttribute("data-i"))
              }
            >Click</button>
          </li>);
          i++;
      }
      return ret
  }
  render(){
      return (
          this.getRows2()
      )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<List />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Yup I got it now, Thanks. I was just confused as to why map and for were behaving differently, it was due to closures

Answer (score -1):

`You can't push a JSX element inside an array`.
This code is totally wrong :

```
getRows2(){ 
   let ret = []
   let i = 0 
   for (const row of this.data){ ret.push(<li>{row, i}<button onClick={()=>{alert(i)}}>Click</button></li>) i++; } 
  return ret 
}
```

And you need to clean your code as this :

```
render(){
   return (
      <ul>
         {this.data.map((el, index)=>{
             return (<li>{el}<button onClick={()=>{alert(index)}}>Click</button></li>) })
         }
      </ul>
   )
}
```

Comment: But he already provided a map condition as `getRows()`... he wanted the same behavior with `for of` as per `getRows2()`